# How to fix $(this).val returning error inside jquery's ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Inside ajax success call, $(this).val() returns error;

I have a table where I am appending some values from database.
I am wrapping my data using `<div contenteditable = "true">`.
So, when I edit my table I want to get the changed/updated data.

So, in my ajax success call I am appending data to table and using `$(selector).on("blur")` method to try to get the updated data.

But, `$(this).val()` returns this error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at w.fn.init.val`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.option").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

    console.log(value);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '/ajax',
      data: {
        value: value
      },
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.length === 0) {

        } else {
          console.log(result);

          let data = result;

          $.each(data, (index, item) => {
            $(".tableData").append(`<tr>
                    <td><div contenteditable = "true" class="edible">${item.st_id}</div></td>
                    <td><div contenteditable = "true" class="edible">${item.co1}</div></td>
                  </tr>`);
          })
          $(".edible").blur((e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log($(this).val())
          })
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I understand the problem here is that when manually accessing `$(this)` it refers to the window itself rather than the element I am trying to access. But I have zero ideas how to access the edited/updated table data.

Comment: Protip: `edible` is a recipe for frustration with any other developer who touches your code. I'd go with `editable`.

Comment: Arrow functions inherit `this` from the outer scope. In your case `this` will be tied to whatever `this` is when `success` is called. You can simply change your arrow function to a regular function to fix this problem (assuming that you want `this` to reference the `.edible` element).